# How to apply disabled style for Input not only to the input itself but to container?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using Input from react-native-elements and when I add the disabledInputstyle it only changes the input (well, just like the name suggests). I know I can do it myself by using useState and defining the disabled state etc., but I wonder if there is anything else so that the style will be applied to the entire container?

```
<Input
  placeholder="Select"
  containerStyle={{...}}
  inputContainerStyle={{...}}
  disabled={!searchResultId}
  disabledInputStyle={{backgroundColor: "grey"}}
  leftIcon={
       <Icon
          name="arrow-drop-down"
          type="materialicons"
       />
           }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading RNE's input [documentation](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/input) i don't see any other prop for the disabled state you want. But reading you question i don't see the need of using useState since you have your disabled value `searchResultId`.

You could do an inline conditional render for the style you want the disabled state you have inside either `containerStyle`  or `inputContainerStyle`  or any other style prop the component supports.

For e.x

```
const containerStyle = !searchResultId ? disabledStyle : normalStyle;
<Input 
placeholder="Select"
containerStyle={containerStyle}
...restProps />
```